# Абстрактные классы в Delphi

Tags: ооп, delphi

Допустим, есть базовый класс. В нем объявляем abstract virtual функцию. В наследнике реализуем эту функцию (перекрываем override). Вопрос: можно ли вызывать эту функцию в базовом классе?
ПС: Спрашиваю потому, что встретился с такой ситуацией в чужом коде. До этого думал, что это невозможно.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно. Смысл в том, что экземпляров базового абстрактного класса у вас никогда не будет. Будет экземпляр конкретного дочернего класса, в котором этот метод точно переопределен.

Этот шаблон проектирования, кстати, называется Шаблонный метод (Template method): в базовом абстрактном классе мы собираем некоторый алгоритм из абстрактных методов. И уже от дочерних конкретных классов будет зависеть работа этого алгоритма.

---

Пример: в базовом классе TCocktail определяется процедура приготовления коктейля. Дочерние классы реализуют конкретные этапы этого процесса.

Базовый класс:

```
type
  TCocktail = class
  protected
    procedure AddFirstIngridient(); virtual; abstract; //Добавление первого ингридиента
    procedure AddSeconsIngridient(); virtual; abstract; //Добавление второго ингридиента
    procedure AddDecorations(); virtual; abstract; //Добавление украшений
    function GetName(): string; virtual; abstract; //Название
  public
    procedure Prepare; //Алгоритм приготовления коктейля
  end;

{ TCocktail }

procedure TCocktail.Prepare;
begin
  writeln('Готовим коктейль ' + GetName());
  AddFirstIngridient();
  AddSeconsIngridient();
  AddDecorations();
  writeln('Ваш коктейль готов');
end;
```

Первый коктейль

```
type
  TBloodyMary = class (TCocktail)
  protected
    procedure AddFirstIngridient();override;
    procedure AddSeconsIngridient();override;
    procedure AddDecorations();override;
    function GetName(): string;override;
  end;

{ TBloodyMary }

procedure TBloodyMary.AddDecorations;
begin
  writeln('Добавляем лед');
end;

procedure TBloodyMary.AddFirstIngridient;
begin
  writeln('50мл водки');
end;

procedure TBloodyMary.AddSeconsIngridient;
begin
  writeln('150мл томатного сока');
end;

function TBloodyMary.GetName: string;
begin
  result := 'Кровавая Мэри';
end;
```

Второй коктейль

```
type
  TIrishCoffee = class (TCocktail)
  protected
    procedure AddFirstIngridient();override;
    procedure AddSeconsIngridient();override;
    procedure AddDecorations();override;
    function GetName(): string;override;
  end;

{ TBloodyMary }

procedure TIrishCoffee.AddDecorations;
begin
  writeln('50 сливки (33%)');
end;

procedure TIrishCoffee.AddFirstIngridient;
begin
  writeln('50мл ирландского виски');
end;

procedure TIrishCoffee.AddSeconsIngridient;
begin
  writeln('80мл кофе');
end;

function TIrishCoffee.GetName: string;
begin
  result := 'Ирландский кофе';
end;
```

Ну и сам код:

```
var cocktail: TCocktail;
begin
  cocktail := TBloodyMary.Create;
  cocktail.Prepare;

  cocktail := TIrishCoffee.Create;
  cocktail.Prepare;

  readln;
end.
```

Comment: А можно минимальный пример?

Comment: плюс два )

Answer (score -1):

Вызов перекрытого родительского метода осуществляется служебным словом **inherited**.

Comment: Не в кассу. Вопрос не о вызове перекрываемого родительского метода из дочернего класса, а о вызове имплементирующего дочернего из родительского.

Comment: Упс, прошу прощения, не внимательно прочитал вопрос.